# Android onDownloadStart get file name and extension from url

Tags: android

I am trying to download files inside my Webview. I use `DownloladListener` to handle download request and then I use `DownloadManager` to download file. Everything works well but I can't get name and extension of file from url's like this one: http://unionpeer.com/dl.php?t=1502119 (This is assassins creed movie .torrent file). How can I get at least file extension? Thanks in advance!

Downloading the file:

```
String url = (String) objects[0];

    String defaultDownloadPath = String.valueOf(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS));

    DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager) context.getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
    DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url));

    request.setAllowedNetworkTypes(DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI | DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_MOBILE)
            .setAllowedOverRoaming(true).setTitle(getFileName(url))
            .setDescription("Download")
            .setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(getPublicExternalPath(defaultDownloadPath),
                    getFileName(url));
    dm.enqueue(request);
```

getfileName() - works a little better than URLUtils.guessFileNameFromUrl()

```
String temp = "";
    String extension = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf("."));
    for (int i = 0; i < extension.length(); i++) {
        if (i != 0){
            if (!Character.isLetter(extension.charAt(i)) && !Character.isDigit(extension.charAt(i))) {
                 break;
            }
        }
        temp += extension.charAt(i);
    }
    return String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis() + temp);
```

Comment: now what you are getting

Comment: I am using URLUtils.guessFileNameFromUrl() and get "dl.php"

Comment: please show your code how you are downloading it

Comment: I updated the post with code

Comment: how you are getting setTitle ? please paste code for getFileName(url) ?

Comment: I updated the post

Comment: inside setDestinationInExternalPublicDir() you are using getFileName() which sets file name and eventually it stored on device with that name. you have to give valid name and extension of file their.